# Creating an Network IP Scanner in python2

Tags: python

I have been developing a piece of software that I can hopefully get your help on. I have been having an issue where the variable "IPrange" keeps increasing but its only ment to increase it when it gets to its max value which is "255" I'm going to put the code on a seperate website "https://www.dropbox.com/s/a5a2jbbdjmuppnt/code.txt?dl=0" it is on Dropbox. there are a few other issues with it if you download the code and run it you can see the issues with it that I still need to resolve but can't think of how to question.

Comment: You should include your code directly. You should directly ask what you have problems with (state the error / your input / the output / what you expected).

Comment: What the problem is I am trying to get the IPrange to stay at 0 while it goes through the other 192.168.0.x possibilities thats my current issue.

Comment: You may want to read "**Violent-Python - Chapter 2 - Building a Port Scanner**" .

Comment: Could you link that to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are increasing the IPrange in the loop.

```
    if IPrange == 255:
        IPrange = 0
    else:
        IPrange += 1

    if IPendnum == 255:
        IPendnum = 1
    else:
        IPendnum += 1
```

I think you meant to increase it when the IPendnum reaches 255.

```
    if IPrange == 255:
        IPrange = 0

    if IPendnum == 255:
        IPendnum = 1
        IPrange += 1
    else:
        IPendnum += 1
```